# $R[\mathbb{Z_{\ge 0}}]$ is isomorphic to $R[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am wondering why the monoid ring $R[\mathbb{Z_{\ge 0}}]$ is isomorphic to $R[X]$.

Has anyone references or an hint on this?

Thank you.

Comment: The isomorphism takes $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\subset R[\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}]$ to $X^n\in R[X]$.

Comment: So if $\chi_m$ is the characteristic function of $m\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$, I send $\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}}r_{m}\chi_m$ to $\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}}r_{m}X^m$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show this easily by checking that they both satisfy the same universal properties (the free commutative $R$-algebra on one generator).

Here's how I would explain it, which gives a more general proof: since the free $R$-module functor is strong monoidal (it sends products to tensor products), it sends monoids to $R$-algebras. Thus, for example, $R[\mathbb{N}]$ is just the free $R$-module functor applied to $\mathbb{N}$ (with multiplication just given by applying the functor). Now using the universal properties check that the the free $R$-module functor applied after the free commutative monoid functor is just the free commutative $R$-algebra functor.